# The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I started my first amp html. But using the code from here:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/basic_markup

Shows me an error on Google Chrome for this tag:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

Error Message:
**The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.**

Comment: I found the reason. I didn't use a server. If open the html file without server Chrome debug tool shows the script error. But if I use a server the error doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AMP spec](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#html-tags), `script` tags are **prohibited** unless the type is `application/ld+json` or it's the loading of the AMP runtime (as per above). Make sure the runtime loader is in the `head` tag and you don't have any other scripts being loaded on the page.

Using the markup found [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/basic_markup), I do not receive any error in Chrome 54.0.2840.99m.